# Why is this Map not populating when I'm evaluating this code in Eclipse?

Tags: scala, scala-ide

Below code should populate a Map but when I do a `val test = userDataMap.get("test").get` the value is null. Whis is this occuring ? This seems to be the correct way of populating a Map ?

```
var userDataMap = Map.empty[String, List[String]]
userDataMap += ("test" -> List("test"))
```

Comment: Are you using the Map coming form the mutable package?

Comment: it works fine for me (2.10, no additional imports)

Comment: @om-nom-nom ok, now im really confused, on Eclipse debug tool the value is null but when I print the value to console the value is there. So perhaps this is a bug in the Scala Eclipse plugin ?

Comment: Might be, or just evaluation order, anyways, I tried this in REPL

Comment: thanks +1, I should have tried this initially